# High IO wait - How to determine the root cause?

Tags: linux, mysql, raid, io, software-raid

I have a MySQL instance on two dedicated servers. One for the production, the other for the test platform.

The 2 servers are pretty the same, the only difference is the RAID controller and the virtual volume (HD are the same). On the production, there is a dedicated HW RAID controller and a RAID 10 volume. On the other, the RAID controller seems to be software (Lenovo ThinkServer RAID 110i) and the volume is RAID 5.

We noticed that during MySQL commits, we have high iowait:

```
while true; do date; ps auxf | awk '{if($8=="D") print $0;}'; sleep 1; done
root     26661  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Jun09   5:41  \_ [jbd2/dm-14-8]
root     26691  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Jun09   0:57  \_ [jbd2/dm-10-8]
Thu Jun 18 13:49:37 CEST 2015
root     26691  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Jun09   0:57  \_ [jbd2/dm-10-8]
Thu Jun 18 13:49:38 CEST 2015
root      1474  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Jun04   0:23  \_ [jbd2/dm-5-8]
root     26691  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Jun09   0:57  \_ [jbd2/dm-10-8]
Thu Jun 18 13:49:39 CEST 2015
Thu Jun 18 13:49:40 CEST 2015
root      1474  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Jun04   0:23  \_ [jbd2/dm-5-8]
root      1478  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Jun04   0:03  \_ [jbd2/dm-7-8]
root     26661  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Jun09   5:41  \_ [jbd2/dm-14-8]
```

dm-10-8 & dm-14-8 are related to database partitions.

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  3 240904 809656 572624 7114416    0    0    59  1681 2002 5141  3  1 67 30  0
 0  4 240880 809656 572632 7114604    0    0   139  2069 2090 4985  3  1 67 29  0
 1  2 240880 809284 572636 7114676    0    0    27  2159 2253 4247  2  1 72 25  0
 5  2 240880 809408 572656 7114820    0    0    27  2404 2254 5350  3  1 69 27  0
```

I suspect the raid controller, how can I be sure?

Comment: Maybe off topic: But why RAID5 on a database? Bad idea due to the write gap.  HW with BBU mitigates this somewhat, but RAID 5 is basically good for reading, not for writing small transactions.

Comment: Because I had no choice... RAID 10 was not supported on this RAID controller (with my version of RHEL)...

Comment: @BobSauvage any progress?

Comment: just to be clear: does io-wait include also wait on file descriptors not provided by mass storage ? like sockets...

Answer (score 7):

My answer had 2 parts: investigation of the block device driver; and optimisation worth looking at with your use case. But I removed last part as it was reported that it can lead to data loss. See comments.

## Investigation of Hardware

I understood that for the same application but on 2 different sets of hardware the performance is very different and you would like to understand why. Therefore I propose first a means to help you find an answer for the "why".

For performance, I often refer to the [Linux Performance Map](http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html) providing by Brendan Gregg on his blog. One can see that for the low level (closest to hardware) a tool like `blktrace` would be perfect.

Not really knowing this tool, I search around and found this [interesting article regarding blktrace](https://brooker.co.za/blog/2013/07/14/io-performance.html) by Marc Brooker. Basically it suggests the following: performing an I/O trace using `blktrace`; using the [btt](https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~aaronc/iosched/doc/btt.html) tool to extract info from this trace. That would be something like this (for a 30 s trace):

```
# blktrace -w 30 -d /dev/dm-10-8 -o dm-10-8
# blkparse -d blkmerged.out dm-10-8*
# btt -i blkmerged.out | less
```

The output can be quite long, but look for D2C entries. It will give you an idea of the time it takes for an I/O delivered to the device driver to be reported as completed by this driver.

Example output (`dnf upgrade` running on a VirtualBox VM on my busy laptop):

```
            ALL           MIN           AVG           MAX           N
--------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- -----------

...
D2C               0.000046515   0.045781696   3.940577359       11713
...
```

It shows a disappointing average of 45 ms per I/O with up to 3,94 s for the worst case!!

For more ways to use blktrace to perform this investigation, read the article from Marc Brooker, very instructive.

Comment: The Percona blog post referenced in the answer [tweak to improve innodb performance](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/05/23/improve-innodb-performance-write-bound-loads/) has been updated with: **Update: do not do this, this has been proven to corrupt data!**

Comment: @vkats thanks a lot. I’ve updated the answer to remove the suggestion and article.

Answer (score 1):

jbd2 process is for ext4 journalling. It is logical that filesystem needs to write into journal during mysql commits, this should not be reason for any worries. The amount of load caused by jbd is influenced by your mount parameters for dm-10-8 and dm-14-8 partitions. It is probably desirable to have very conservatiove journalling at database partition to ensure that your database does not get corrupted if something happens and your server accidentally reboots. You can select another journalling mount options in test environment just for comparison.

Comment: my jbd2/dm-2-8 seems all the time around 8.5% at iotop, but.. I dont think that is problematic as there is no disk read, and the total disk write is 35mb after 1hour. btw, at /dev there is at most dm-2 (that -8 I have no idea where it is from..)